# Facebook->getSession()

Tags: php, facebook

I have 2 very simple scripts:

```
<?php

require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
'cookie' => true,
));
?>
```

and

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
/* Get a valid session */
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me = null;
if($session) {
/* Check if session is valid */
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
}
if ($me) {
echo 'User is logged in and has a valid session';
}
else {
echo 'Session expired or user has not logged in yet. 
Redirecting...';
echo '<script> top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl()
  .'";</script>';
}
?>
```

Why do I get *Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in C:\wamp\www\jt1\index.php on line 4*?

Comment: Are you sure that the Facebook API's files are in the same directory? And do you have included the correct files?

Comment: What php sdk version do you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `getSession()` method in modern facebook PHP SDKm use `getUser()` instead.

And see sample at https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: I am following the Packt 2011 book.  Sucks eh? :(

Answer (score 0):

$facebook variable is NOT visible to your second script. To prove this, move the logic from the first script that defines $facebook and put it into the second script. It should all begin working.

Comment: Maybe both scripts are in one file - @Jason: are they?

Comment: @Alex Weinstein: wrong, if it wasn't visible we would see a error about calling a method of non-object (because it would be `null` then)

Comment: Right, the first script is "config.php".

Answer (score -2):

I think there is something wrong when you transport the array variable to get a instance!

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'secret' => 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
***'cookie' => true,***
));
```

you should not have comma at the end. you can use "'cookie' => true"

Comment: Wrong, it is **valid** php syntax